# Efficient way to handle multiple CASE statements in SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I run a report in which I have a situation where based on a column value which is basically a Key or Id, I need to fetch corresponding value from the mapping Id table. Something like below:

```
    SELECT
     (case when [column1='A'] then (select value from Table1) 
           when [column1='B'] then (select value from Table2) 
           when [column1='C'] then (select value from Table3)

           and so on uptil 35 more 'when' conditions ...

  ELSE column1 end) Value 
from Table1
```

More precisely:

```
SELECT 
(case when [A.column1='1'] 
then (select value from B where B.clientId=100 and A.column1=B.Id) 
when [A.column1='2'] 
then (select value from C where C.clientId=100 and A.column1=C.Id) 
when [A.column1='3'] 
then (select value from D where D.clientId=100 and A.column1=D.Id) 
...
and so on uptil 30 more 'when' conditions 
...
ELSE column1 end) 
FROM A
```

In Tables B,C,D..so on, we maintain data for all clients. Each client has a specific `ClientId` and these tables B,C,D etc have index in place on `Id` and `ClientId` columns.

Is there an efficient way to handle this in SQL Server?

Comment: And why do you have 30 tables with (what seems to be) identical structure? Can't you combine them in a single table?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that you have appropriate indexes on the tables in the subqueries. I mocked up some quick test data and put 10 million rows in table `A`. I wasn't game to create 30 tables so I just created 3 for the `CASE` expression. I think that 3 is enough to show the general principles.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.B;
CREATE TABLE dbo.B (
    ClientID INT NOT NULL,
    Id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, Id)
);

INSERT INTO B VALUES (100, '1', 'TABLE B'); 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.C;
CREATE TABLE dbo.C (
    ClientID INT NOT NULL,
    Id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, Id)
);

INSERT INTO C VALUES (100, '2', 'TABLE C'); 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.D;
CREATE TABLE dbo.D (
    ClientID INT NOT NULL,
    Id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, Id)
);

INSERT INTO D VALUES (100, '3', 'TABLE D'); 


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.A;
CREATE TABLE dbo.A (
    column1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.A WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT CAST(1 + t.RN % 3 AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (5000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) t;
```

I disabled result sets and ran the following query in SSMS:

```
SELECT A.column1
FROM A;
```

It took around 0.723 seconds. I'm doing pretty unscientific tests because I don't know anything your data. In any case, with serial queries we can't expect a better result than 0.7 seconds. That's our baseline.

The most efficient way to write this query is without joins at all. The key is that the `CASE` expression is only ever going to return 3 (or 30) unique values if it finds a match. You can save off the results into local variables and just use those in the query. The query below finishes in around 1.044 seconds:

```
DECLARE @B_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = (select value from B where B.clientId=100 and B.Id = '1');
DECLARE @C_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = (select value from C where C.clientId=100 and C.Id = '2');
DECLARE @D_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = (select value from D where D.clientId=100 and D.Id = '3');

SELECT 
(case when A.column1='1' then @B_VALUE
      when A.column1='2' then @C_VALUE
      when A.column1='3' then @D_VALUE
      -- omitted other columns
else column1 end) 
FROM A;
```

The plan is very simple:

[image]

For another option you can write the query with joins (where we can rewrite the `CASE` expression in a more compact form, using `COALESCE()`. This finished in around 2.314 seconds:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(B.column1, C.column1, D.column1, -- omitted other columns  
             A.column1)
    -- (case A.column1
    --    when '1' then B.value
    --    when '2' then C.value
    --    when '3' then D.value
    --    -- omitted other columns
    -- else A.column1 end) 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.clientId=100 and B.Id = '1'
LEFT JOIN C ON C.clientId=100 and C.Id = '2'
LEFT JOIN D ON D.clientId=100 and D.Id = '3';
```

Here's the plan:

[image]

You can get a nearly identical runtime and query plan by writing the query like this:

```
SELECT 
(case A.column1
   when '1' then (select value from B where B.clientId=100 and '1'=B.Id) 
   when '2' then (select value from C where C.clientId=100 and '2'=C.Id) 
   when '3' then (select value from D where D.clientId=100 and '3'=D.Id) 
-- omitted other columns
else column1 end) 
FROM A;
```

The original query in the question has an issue: SQL Server is doing a useless sort before the nested loop join. That query finishes in around 5.838 seconds on my machine.

[image]

Trace flag 8690 eliminates the sort as well as the table spools. The query runs in about 7.479 seconds with trace flag 8690, so I suppose that the spools are helpful for this query.

Answer (score 4):

If they are all different tables then this may be your best case scenario.      UNLESS Table1.column1 values can be repeated (multiple rows='1', etc).  In that case you may want to move from subqueries to joins.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN A.column1='1' THEN B.value
    WHEN A.column1='2' THEN C.value
    WHEN A.column1='3' THEN D.value
    and so on uptil 30 more 'when' conditions 
    ELSE A.column1
    END 
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.column1='1' AND A.column1=B.Id AND B.clientId=100
    LEFT JOIN C ON A.column1='2' AND A.column1=C.Id AND C.clientId=100
    LEFT JOIN D ON A.column1='2' AND A.column1=D.Id AND D.clientId=100
```